# Where in the aws management console to modify elastic beanstalk health check url?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I can't seem to find where in the user interface to modify the health check url. I even tried looking directly at the load balancer in the EC2 user interface but the edit HealthCheck button is greyed out there. The aws docs show a ui for the healthcheck, but they do not describe where to find it!

Does anyone know the path to this user interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's under configuration > modify load balancer

You need to make sure to check the box next to the process for who's health check you want to modify otherwise edit health check will be greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the setting for the health check url has been moved since this answer was posted. I was able to find it in the AWS console under EC2 > Target Groups > (click group name) > Health Checks > Edit > Health check path.